# Removing Contacts from LinkedIn

Tags: contacts, linkedin

If I delete a contact from LinkedIn, is there a possibility that I still show up under their "People You May Know" list? I fear this might create an awkward scenario. The person I deleted will be aware that I deleted them because now I show up under that list. Is there any way of preventing this from happening? The person is an ex-coworker. I'll be deleting my employment information soon, so it shouldn't be visible on my profile.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about that. From [LinkedIn help](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/49):

> Note: You can also remove individual connections from the Contacts
>   page by clicking More under their name and selecting Remove
>   Connection. Connections you remove will no longer be a 1st-degree
>   connection to you and they will no longer appear in your Contacts
>   section. They will not be notified that they have been removed. **Only
>   the member that breaks the connection can reinitiate that connection**

Comment: I fully understand that, however can I still show up under the "People You May Know List" for that member since LinkedIn's Algorithm is matching me to them due to something in-common?

People You May Know: http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/29

Answer (score 0):

You see that member in "People You May Know List" because your other connections/friends are connected to that person.